# java.sql.SQLEXCEPTION: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: java

```
public static Connection ConnectDB() {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hms_db","root","golu");
        return con;
    } catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        return null;
    }      
}
```

> ```
> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException  
>   at Login.txtPasswordKeyPressed(Login.java:204)  
>   at Login.access$300(Login.java:14)  
>   at Login$4.keyPressed(Login.java:74)  
>   at java.awt.Component.processKeyEvent(Component.java:6493)  
>   at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(JComponent.java:2832)  
>   at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6312)  
>   at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)  
>   at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)  
>   at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)  
>   at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)  
>   at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1954)
>   at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:806)
>   at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1074)
>   at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:945)
>   at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:771)
>   at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4762)  
>   at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)  
>   at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)  
>   at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)  
>   at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)  
>   at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)  
>   at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)  
>   at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)  
>   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)  
>   at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>   at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
>   at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)  
>   at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)  
>   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)  
>   at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>   at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)  
>   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101) 
>   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)  
>   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
> ```

My username is *"admin"* and password is *"12345"*.
Please someone help me to resolve these error.

Comment: A couple of comments: Don't give out your credentials to the whole world by posting them on Stack Overflow.  Also, does your `1` key still function properly after holding it down for so long?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: When you post an exception stacktrace, then place post the correct one. This one is not related to your question.

Comment: What is here: Login.java, line 204?

Answer (score 0):

You passing 'root' like username and 'golu' like passwork it´s correct? Because in your post you say that the username and password are other.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing wrong username and password for your mysql database to get a jdbc connection.

```
 Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hms_db","<valid-mysql-username>","<valid-mysql-password>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have included [the library of JDBC driver](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) on your project.

And change it:

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/<database name>","<user>","<password>");
```

Comment: not working and yes i have included the library of jdbc driver!